# JSON Exception unexpected character

Tags: callout, json

I am doing a callout to a google script which takes in address and returns back geographic information (lat, lng etc) in the form of JSON string.

The problem is that in the returned JSON string " is replaced by \". So the JSON response is something like :

```
{\"results\":[{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"435\",\"types\":[\"street_number\"],\"short_name\":\"435\"},{\"long_name\":\"West Huron Street\",\"types\":[\"route\"],\"short_name\":\"W Huron St\"},{\"long_name\":\"Old West Side\",\"types\":[\"neighborhood\",\"political\"],\"short_name\":\"Old West Side\"},{\"long_name\":\"Ann Arbor\",\"types\":[\"locality\",\"political\"],\"short_name\":\"Ann Arbor\"},{\"long_name\":\"Washtenaw County\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_2\",\"political\"],\"short_name\":\"Washtenaw County\"},{\"long_name\":\"Michigan\",\"types\":[\"administrative_area_level_1\",\"political\"],\"short_name\":\"MI\"},{\"long_name\":\"United States\",\"types\":[\"country\",\"political\"],\"short_name\":\"US\"},{\"long_name\":\"48103\",\"types\":[\"postal_code\"],\"short_name\":\"48103\"}],\"formatted_address\":\"435 West Huron Street, Ann Arbor, MI 48103, USA\",\"types\":[\"street_address\"],\"geometry\":{\"bounds\":{\"southwest\":{\"lng\":-83.75289409999999,\"lat\":42.28154259999999},\"northeast\":{\"lng\":-83.7528932,\"lat\":42.2815563}},\"viewport\":{\"southwest\":{\"lng\":-83.75424263029151,\"lat\":42.2802004697085},\"northeast\":{\"lng\":-83.75154466970851,\"lat\":42.2828984302915}},\"location_type\":\"RANGE_INTERPOLATED\",\"location\":{\"lng\":-83.75289409999999,\"lat\":42.28154259999999}}}],\"status\":\"OK\"}
```

This gives me an error- System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]

As you can see the " are replaced by \".

To counter this I am doing a replaceAll('\"', '"') but this is not helping. The final string still contains \"

I performed the same replace in my anonymous execute and it worked but it does not work in the apex class.

There already exists a similar question to this one on Stackoverflow but it did not help me much.

Any idea on why the replaceAll() is not working? Or any other way I can remove the \ from the response?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like the response has been escaped so it can be represented as a single string. How are you processing the response? Better to avoid the escaping if possible rather than to try to strip it out after.

Comment: I am reading the response in a string. So its something like this: HttpResponse response = http.send(request);  String jsonResponse = response.getBody();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the built in [String.unescapeEcmaScript()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_unescapeEcmaScript) method to remove the escape characters in that JSON string. This will also take care of any other escaped characters that may be in your string value.

```
// shortened your string value
string original = '{\"results\":[{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"435\",\"types\":[\"street_number\"]';

String s = original.unescapeEcmaScript();
system.debug(s);
```

> DEBUG|{"results":[{"address_components":[{"long_name":"435","types":["street_number"]

Comment: Thanks Mark, it worked. I did not knew a method like this existed.

Comment: This method was part of the 'new' String methods added in Winter '13. There are similar methods for escaping and unescaping CSV, HTML and XML types. https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Winter13/New+String+Methods

Comment: Nice. Sometimes the new stuff takes a while to put in your tool belt. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace all the \ in the string

```
String s = '{\"results\":[{\"address_components\":[{\"long_name\":\"435\",\"types\":[\"street_number\"]';
s = s.replaceAll('[\\\\]','');
system.debug(logginglevel.error,s);
```

Do you have any control over the JSON output from the external system? You can have it format the output to not put in the \ character if you have any control over it

Comment: I do have control over the response from the google script, however the \ character is not put in from the google script. It happens when the response is read in the apex class in a string.