# Get JSONException with valid JSON. How to figure out what's wrong?

Tags: json, httpcalloutmock, deserialize

I have a bit of JSON coming from a mock that needs to de deserialized into an object. The JSON itself is perfectly valid. It has been validated by multiple services, and they all say it looks legit.

However, I consequently get

`System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name at [line:1, column:3]`

Which is odd, because there is not even a single backslash character in the file.

Then, when I fold the JSON into 'compact' form, removing all spaces, tabs, indentation etc, it suddenly works.

Any clues? Anybody had something similar before?

Comment: Can you post sample json response. Also [validate json response](https://jsonlint.com/) which you get.

Comment: Sorry can't post it, it is a huge file and contains confidential details. I was just wondering if it rings a bell with someone who had experienced an identical situation. And yes, as mentiond, I validated the JSON multiple times using different linters/validators.

Comment: Found similar issue **[here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33344/json-exception-unexpected-character/33353#33353)**

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue or something. Since it's at 1:3, maybe you could just give us like... the first 5-6 characters of your JSON? Or just look for anything unusual around that location.

Comment: leading line break?